# Initialising variable with getter in Constructor

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, getter

If I have a class Car with a getter like this:

```
public int getDirection(){
   return this.direction;
}
```

and a Subclass that extends car:

```
public class Ecar extends Car{
}
```

Are there differences if I initialize the value direction as shown in the following examples:

1)

---

```
int direction; 
public Ecar(){ 
this.direction = getDirection();
}
```

---

2)

---

```
public Ecar(){...}
int direction = getDirection();
```

---

3)

---

```
int direction = super.getDirection();
```

---

4)

---

```
int direction = this.getDirection();
```

---

Comment: You realize when you do `this.direction = getDirection()`, it's like doing `this.direction = this.direction`, right? You need to pass `direction` as an argument to the constructor

Comment: @user but getDirection is from the upper class. So shouldn´t the value of the upper class be assigned to this.direction if I call getDirection in the subclass?

Comment: If you already have a direction field in a superclass, why are you shadowing it in `Ecar`? Also, in your constructor, the direction field will be null

Comment: @user if a condition is met i´ll be overwriting it in the subclass.

Comment: Then make a setter in `Car` itself. `direction` hasn't been set while you're in the constructor anyways. This repetition will probably just cause you problems

Comment: No difference!!! Ran all Your scenarios .

Comment: @user Yes.. that way we will have an uninitialized direction. But I kept this simple, as it looks, the questioner is more interested in the sub class behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All scenarios giving same result.

I have used a sample value as 10 for direction

```
public class Car {
    int direction=10;
    public int getDirection(){
        return this.direction;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ecar e = new Ecar();
        e.print();
    }
}

class Ecar extends Car{

//    Case 1
//    int direction;
//    public Ecar(){
//        this.direction = getDirection();
//    }

//    case 2
//    int direction = this.getDirection();

//    case3
//    int direction = super.getDirection();

//    case 4
//    int direction = this.getDirection();

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.direction);
    }
}
```